# Как подключить Python бота к чату на сайте

Tags: python, telegram, бот

На сайте есть чат, туда, примерно раз в 2 часа закидывают рекламу битков. Знакомый попросил создать бота. Возможность подключения ботов к сайту есть, но не к чату.(Слава Тору(лук который))
В гугле выдаёт не те ответы... в основном как создать чат-бота, а не как подключить к чату. Ну и по этой теме: как создать правильно проверку, чтобы реклама одна за другой не выкидывалась, а только после того,  как в этот чат кто-то закинул свою битхрень... Большое спасибо за внимание и понимание к таким новичкам как я. Ваша помощь просто бесценна!!! Многое познаётся и изучается с вашей помощью!

Comment: Не очень понятно, при чём тут телеграмм, если чат на сайте? Или сайт просто выводит на страницу содержимое телеграмм-канала? Опишите этот момент подробнее.

Comment: Xander,  я имею ввиду внутренний чат сайта.  Мне бы хотелось создать бота и как-то подключиться к нему. Но я не знаю как получить от туда информацию и отправить туда, кроме как в ручную))

Comment: Но тогда я вообще не понимаю, при чём тут телеграм

Comment: Xander,  я тоже))  мне просто нужно сделать бота, но я не знаю как ЭТО реализовать... в вк,дискорд,  в вотс  апп это легко,  а как тут я просто хз... наверное надо изобретать какого-то робота, что-ли... но опять как получать и отправлять информацию от туда я просто хз... Ооочень сложно для новичка

Comment: Ну тогда получается, что вам нужно просто копать код сайта и смотреть, как там реализован этот чат. И, скорее всего, код вашего бота нужно будет вписать прямо в код сайта.

Comment: Xander, к сожалению,  это невозможно... А других методов нет?